# How to store lists over criteria in Python?

Tags: python

I'm producing lists of data iteratively. Each of these lists has the same number of values, and my goal is to store the `N` worst lists, this criteria being defined by a specific column.
I've tried several things, but none of them satisfy me, and I'd like to know if I missed something.

For the example, let's imagine each of my rows contains 5 elements, and that I want to keep the 10 worst rows.
I want to compare on the last value, knowing this one is always positive.

```
array = [[0] * 5] * 10
while (...)
    # processing
    # I now have a "my_row" that looks like [5, 102.24, -3.12, 2, 7.37] for instance
    indexes = [array.index(row) for row in array if row[-1] == min(r[-1] for r in array)] # can return several indexes
    if array[indexes[0]][-1] < my_row[-1]:
        array[indexes[0]] = my_row
```

However, this solution is far from being elegant, nor optimal.
Does anyone have an idea how to code it better?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is the "best row" for you?

Comment: *my goal is to store the N worse lists* and *I want to keep the 10 best rows* which is it?

Comment: Corrected that mistake, i meant worse both times, being worse meaning having the highest value in the last field

Comment: so lowest means worst?

Comment: 0 would be perfect, and the highest is the worse (that's why I initialise my array with 0)

Comment: So basically you want the ten rows with the highest last values? Why are you looking for the min if you want the max? Also realistically how many rows will you be keeping as the N worst?

Comment: I was looking for the min in order to replace this one. Realistically, i'm actually keeping 10 lines for the moment, but this will be a user parameter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79655/discussion-between-ena-and-padraic-cunningham).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [sortedContainers](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/introduction.html) library has a `sortedlistwithkey` container that will do what you want:

```
rows = [[5, 102.24, -3.12, 2, 9.36], [2, 102.24, -3.12, 2, 388], [2, 102.24, -3.12, 1, 1.54],
        [5, 102.24, -3.12, 2, 1.11], [5, 102.24, -3.12, 2, 7.35], [5, 102.24, -3.12, 2, 54],
        [5, 102.24, -3.12, 2, 1.53]]

from sortedcontainers import sortedlistwithkey
from operator import itemgetter
array = sortedlistwithkey.SortedListWithKey(key=itemgetter(-1))

n = 3
for row in rows:
    array.add(row)
    if len(array) > n:
            array.pop(0)
print(array.as_list())
```

Output:

```
[[5, 102.24, -3.12, 2, 9.36], [5, 102.24, -3.12, 2, 54], [2, 102.24, -3.12, 2, 388]]
```

All you have to do is pop the the lowest element each time.

Or negate the key value and pop from the end:

```
from sortedcontainers import sortedlistwithkey

array = sortedlistwithkey.SortedListWithKey(key=lambda x: -x[-1])
n = 3
for row in rows:
    array.add(row)
    if len(array) > n:
        array.pop()
print(array.as_list())
```

Output:

```
[[2, 102.24, -3.12, 2, 388], [5, 102.24, -3.12, 2, 54], [5, 102.24, -3.12, 2, 9.36]]
```

The most size array will grow to is n+1 and you don't have to sort, copy or slice.

You can also slightly modify the bisect_right function if you only care about the last value:

```
def bisect_right(a, x, lo=0, hi=None):
    if lo < 0:
        raise ValueError('lo must be non-negative')
    if hi is None:
        hi = len(a)
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo + hi) // 2
        if x > a[mid][-1]:
            hi = mid
        else:
            lo = mid + 1
    return lo

array = []
n = 3
for row in rows:
    b = bisect_right(array, row[-1])
    array.insert(b, row)
    if len(array) > n:
        array.pop()
print(array)
```

Output:

```
[[2, 102.24, -3.12, 2, 388], [5, 102.24, -3.12, 2, 100], [2, 102.24, -3.12, 97]]
```

Rows where all have the same max value:

```
rows = [ [5, 102.24, -3.12, 2, 100], [2, 102.24, -3.12, 2, 2], [2, 102.24, -3.12, 97],
        [5, 102.24, -3.12, 2, 1.11], [5, 102.24, -3.12, 2, 23], [5, 102.24, -3.12, 2, 54],
        [5, 102.24, -3.12, 2, 1.53], [5, 102.24, -3.12, 2, 100], [5, 102.24, -3.12, 2, 100]]
```

Output:

```
[[5, 102.24, -3.12, 2, 100], [5, 102.24, -3.12, 2, 100], [5, 102.24, -3.12, 2, 100]]
```

You can also pass more keys to `sortedlistwithkey` if you care about more than one value:

```
array = sortedlistwithkey.SortedListWithKey(key=lambda x: (-x[-1], -x[-2]))
```

You could also speed up the bisect_function by doing some simple type casting and compile with cython:

```
def bisect_right(a, int x, int lo=0, int hi= -1):
    cdef int mid
    if lo < 0:
        raise ValueError('lo must be non-negative')
    if hi == -1:
        hi = len(a)
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo + hi) // 2
        if x > a[mid][-1]:
            hi = mid
        else:
            lo = mid + 1
    return lo
```

Comment: So the last column will be used as a key? The thing is, rows can have the same value for the last column, will it be compatible with key system?

Comment: @ena, if you are taking the max `n` rows then it will give you the output as per the edit, bear in mind you might have more values that have 100 as the max but if you want `n`  and you are only considering the last value then yes this will work

Comment: You are only checking the last value in your own code so this is the same

Answer (score 0):

First of all `[[0] * 5] * 10` doesn't create a proper list for you have create a nested list that all of its elements are point to one object (one address) you can create it with a list comprehension :

```
array = [[0 for _ in range(5)] for _ in range(10)]
```

and for your code you can use `zip` function to get a the columns and instead of `list.index` you can use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) :

```
while (...)
    # processing
    # I now have a "my_row" that looks like [5, 102.24, -3.12, 2, 7.37] for instance
    col=zip(*array)
    indexes = [i for i,row in enumerate(array) if row[-1] == min(col[-1])] # can return several indexes
    if array[indexes[0]][-1] < my_row[-1]:
        array[indexes[0]] = my_row
```

Also based on actually what you want to do it can be more efficient for example of you dealing with large list you can use `itertools` module for example using `itertools.izip` instead of `zip` . or you can reduce your conditions.and for example if you want one row in array that its last row is minimum you can simply use `min` function with a `key` function :

```
from operator import itemgetter
index = min(enumerate(array),key=lambda x:itemgetter(-1)(x[1]))[0]
```

As another example consider the following nested list :

```
>>> array = [[i for i in range(5)] for _ in  range(10)]
>>> array
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]

>>> import random
>>> for i in array:
...   random.shuffle(i)
... 
>>> array
[[1, 2, 4, 0, 3], [2, 1, 0, 4, 3], [2, 0, 3, 4, 1], [4, 3, 2, 0, 1], [4, 3, 2, 1, 0], [0, 2, 4, 1, 3], [1, 4, 0, 3, 2], [2, 3, 1, 0, 4], [2, 3, 4, 0, 1], [3, 4, 2, 0, 1]]
```

And now i want to fine the row with minimum last item :

```
>>> index =min(enumerate(array),key=lambda x:itemgetter(-1)(x[1]))[0]
>>> index
4
```

And you can use `heapq.nlargest` to get the `N` largest elements.For example you can use following code to get the top 5 rows based on those last element:

```
>>> heapq.nlargest(5,array,key=itemgetter(-1))
[[2, 3, 1, 0, 4], [1, 2, 4, 0, 3], [2, 1, 0, 4, 3], [0, 2, 4, 1, 3], [1, 4, 0, 3, 2]]
```

And if you want those indices you can use `zip` and `enumerate`:

```
>>> zip(*heapq.nlargest(5,enumerate(array),key=lambda x:itemgetter(-1)(x[1])))[0]
(7, 0, 1, 5, 6)
```

Comment: I corrected my original code, but I still don't understand this answer: the range part gives me a list of 50 lists containing each a zero

Comment: @ena What you mean by *keep the 10 worse rows*

Comment: @ena Yeah it does , its what you wanted to get in your question with `[[0] * 5] * 10`

Comment: Not quite. Using 2 and 3 instead of 5 and 10, i get "[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]" with my method, "[[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]]" with yours

Comment: @ena Yeah i change it and edited eh answer! so What you mean by keep the 10 worse rows

Comment: The more the last field of the row is high, the worse this row is

Comment: @ena do you mean something like `heapq.nlargest`? checkout the edit

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure I follow your sample code (your use of "row" to refer to two different things in the same statement doesn't help), so I made a simpler example, where the data is strings - but you could use arrays or tuples or arbitrary objects, since you can define a custom "criteria" function for sorting:

```
data = ["abc", "bup", "zok", "foo", "gek", "ick"]
criteria = lambda item: item[1] # use any rule you want instead
N = 3

toplist = sorted(data[:N], key=criteria)
for item in data[N:]:
    if criteria(item) < criteria(toplist[-1]):
        toplist.append(item)
        toplist = sorted(toplist, key=criteria)
        toplist = toplist[:N] # only keep the top N items

print toplist
```

at the end, "toplist" is your top N elements according to your criteria

**Notes on Performance:**

Sorting won't be horribly expensive since you're sorting maximum N+1 elements each time, and only do so if there actually is an element to be added (which should be a minority if you don't have pathological data).

You could slightlty improve things by exploiting the fact that the list is already sorted and using an insert_in_sorted function, that's left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Your answer looks like what I needed! However, on the sorting part, i'm treating millions of data, and sorting at each line might be quite expensive at the end

Comment: So, comparing the last element only, and if it's indeed higher, then I can append the row and sort, right?

Comment: yes, you can compare to the smallest last element to see if it's worth inserting at all (I originally started writing it that way, but then I prefered to keep the code simple - you need to compare using the "criteria" function, and also check if the list is smaller than N) ... hmm, actually, there's a quicker way, I'll edit it

Comment: I edited it; initializing toplist with the (sorted) first 3 elements removes the need for checking all the time whether toplist is full etc.

Comment: If you sort the original data, why would you need a loop at all?

Comment: I only sort the first N elements of the data, which is a pretty big difference (OP seems to be saying N=10, but the data is millions of items).

Comment: what is that supposed to be doing?

Comment: ? I'm not sure I understand your question. I just make sure at all time that toplist is a sorted list of N items.

Comment: My original data is generated iteratively, I can't sort it upstream. What I thought I understand was to compare the current row with the last "kept" row, and if its value is superior, delete the last kept row, add the current one, then sort again

Comment: ena: yes, that's what my example does now - with "if criteria(item) < criteria(toplist[-1])"

Comment: though yeah if your data is from a generator you can modify the code accordingly, something like "for item in generator, if len(toplist) < N or toplist[-1] ... etc.

Comment: Exactly what I did! Seems to work fine. Thanks again!